# Precision error in addition while calculating large Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c++

My program calculates the following Fibonacci sequences:

- [77th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bElFk.jpg) 5527939700884757
- [78th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpGJG.jpg) 8944394323791464
- [79th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PrUT.jpg) 14472334024676220

But clearly, if I add last two digits of number 77th and 78th number it should 1, I cannot understand this problem

```
long double iterative_fib(int n){
   long double firstNumber = 0;
   long double secondNumber = 1;
   long double thirdNumber = 0;

   for (int i = 0;i <n-1;i++)
   {
       if ( n == 0)
       {
           cout << "The fibonacci number is: " << n;
       }
       else
       {
           thirdNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber;
           firstNumber = secondNumber;
           secondNumber = thirdNumber;
       }
   }
   return thirdNumber;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will not be able to tell what the problem is from looking at your screen results. Please provide a minimum amount of code for us to look at

Comment: Are you using long long int as your datatype?

Comment: @HarisNadeem I wrote the code. Thank you.

Comment: @DeepakAhire I am using long double.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also recommend you read [this Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and that you read *all* of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons you get negative votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `long double` as your cumulative data type, you are opening yourself up to the precision limits of the type, which is usually around [17 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/476212/314291).

Since fibonacci numbers are all positive integers, I would instead use a `unsigned long long` to represent the integers - this is good for a signed integer representation of `2^64-1`, i.e. at least 19 digits of precision.

```
unsigned long long iterative_fib(int n){
   unsigned long long firstNumber = 0;
   unsigned long long secondNumber = 1;
   unsigned long long thirdNumber = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
   {
       thirdNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber;
       firstNumber = secondNumber;
       secondNumber = thirdNumber;
   }
   return thirdNumber;
}
```

Which returns the correct answer, `14472334024676221`

[IdeOne example here](https://ideone.com/cY9TC5)

However, beyond 19 digits, you'll need to resort to a [Big Integer representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507121/c-big-integer) library, or roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

When working with number sequences such as Fibonacci numbers, if one uses an approach where one tries to store a number in a sequence in a specific type, such as `long long` or `unsigned long long`, eventually it will become impossible to store large values, so one needs to change the strategy. In that case, for example, strings could be used to store digits of a large number, and any operation you perform would have to be digit-wise. Also, issue similar to the one you have has been addressed in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255628/how-to-store-output-of-very-large-fibonacci-number)